# Which PHP Array Function Should Be Used To Match a String to the First Part of a Delimited Line and Return the Second Part of the Delimited Line

Tags: php, arrays, explode, csv

Which php array function should be used to match a string to the first part of a delimited line and return the second part of the delimited line? The reason I am using an array is because I have many delimited text lines in a file. ex:

```
contact-us.php = Contact Us- Test Bed
```

I need some way to match the pages filename to the first part of the delimited line, and return it's second part. I have tried a few different array functions but I do not know which one to use or how to implement the array function assuming that I have found the correct one. This is the code that I devised and it is located in the head of the php file. Once the correct page title is chosen, I will simply print it into the title tags.

```
function getPageName()
{
    return substr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],strrpos($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"],"/")+1); // If one echo's this and the url is /TestBed/contact-us.php Output will be: contact-us.php
}

function pageTitleIdentifier ()
{
    $filename = 'http://localhost/TestBed/includes/apptop/title.txt';
    $mode = 'rb';
    $file_handle = fopen ($filename, $mode);

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $page_title_pair = fgets($file_handle); // This will start reading where the above while loop stopped line by line.
        $parts = explode('=', $page_title_pair);
        @ $pageTitle = $parts[0] . $parts[1]; // Part zero is the filename ex contact-us.php Part one is the Title ex Contact Us- Test Bed for that page.
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
}
```

So, what is the correct way to do this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you may want to consider implementing a caching solution. To parse a file for EVERY request, on a high-traffic server, will definitely add un-necessary load.

Try this:

```
function pageTitleIdentifier ()
{
    $filename = 'http://localhost/TestBed/includes/apptop/title.txt';
    $mode = 'rb';
    $file_handle = fopen ($filename, $mode);

    while (!feof($file_handle)) {

        $page_title_pair = fgets($file_handle); 

        list($script, $title) = explode('=', $page_title_pair);

        // Uncomment below lines for debugging, they must line up exactly
        //   for the condition to be met, breaking the loop
        // var_dump($script);
        // var_dump(getPageName();

        // Because we reading from a file, might be some whitespace issues
        //  trim and strtolower ensures a true apples to apples comparison
        if (trim(strtolower($script)) === trim(strtolower(getPageName()))) {
            return $title;
        }            
    }

    fclose($file_handle);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. It's not working. It's not giving any errors, even with it set to 'notice'. I changed the one line to this `print_r (list($page, $title) = explode('=', $page_title_pair));` It prints this: Array ( [0] => index.php [1] => Test Bed ) Array ( [0] => news.php [1] => News- Test Bed ) Array ( [0] => contact-us.php [1] => Contact Us- Test Bed ) Array ( [0] => about.php [1] => About- Test Bed ) Each line is a new array, but I think that $script is checked after all of the file has been read as is $title. How would I change it so that only one line is read and THEN the comparison is made?

Comment: Do a var_dump(getPageName()), and post results.

Comment: Apperantly this is not the case because this modifing the code like this:  `print_r (list($page, $title) = explode('=', $page_title_pair)); // $script is the filename ex contact-us.php $title is the Title for that page.
 print 'Next';` Prints this: Array ( [0] => index.php [1] => Test Bed ) NextArray ( [0] => news.php [1] => News- Test Bed ) NextArray ( [0] => contact-us.php [1] => Contact Us- Test Bed ) NextArray ( [0] => about.php [1] => About- Test Bed ) Next

Comment: I'll try that in a bit... can't right now. You actually replied and I did not notice so my above comment does not mean what you said won't work since my comment in a way should be above yours.

Comment: Note: There are currently 4 lines in the text file. Ok, when var_dump[...] is in the if loop, nothing happens meaning the if loop is never true.<- I think that is the correct term. When I put it after the list[...] line it outputs this: string(9) "index.php" string(9) "index.php" string(9) "index.php" string(9) "index.php"

Comment: @MindMaster: That makes sense because it is stepping through each row of the file, and the conditional to break the loop hasn't been met. So obviously you are running this from the index.php, page. Does your file have a index.php = MY HOME PAGE entry?

Comment: Yes it does, I also ran this from the contact-us.php page and the results were the same except index.php was replaced with contact-us.php. I'll paste the file contents of the title.txt file. Here's the file contents: index.php = Test Bed news.php = News- Test Bed contact-us.php = Contact Us- Test Bed about.php = About- Test Bed

Comment: Thank you! It was white space that was causing the problem; it must have been taking the whitespace into consideration, but now the white space is all stripped out.

Comment: Ahhh figures. I should have seen it earlier. When reading text from flat-files like this it is a good practice to sanitize the values.